# Extra argument 'ProgressBlock' in call

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm saving the objects to Parse using "Restaurantes.saveinbackground()" and now i want to add an upload progress bar. But i get this error:

"Extra argument 'ProgressBlock' in call"

I have a few images uploading and text. When i copy paste the code from Parse.com, it doesnt work.

**Original**
[image]

**My Code**
[image]

What is wrong? Thank you guys!

Comment: Swift 1.2 or 2.0? In 2.0, the `Bool` needs to be `ObjCBool`. If you use code completion, it will show you the right types. Or omit the types, and it will map them to the right types automatically.

Comment: I think its 1.2... I've tried to add manually but with no success.

Comment: Xcode 6 or 7? When you say "add manually", what do you mean? When you use code completion, what does it prompt you with? What type is `restaurantes`?

Comment: Xcode 6, so i think its 1.2 :)
1) Manually i mean with code completion.
2 )Gives me just "    `Restaurantes.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(<#block: PFBooleanResultBlock?##(Bool, NSError?) -> Void#>)"`
3) "Restaurantes" is the name of the class in Parse.

Comment: Yep, that's not Swift 2 (which is provided via Xcode 7). So that eliminates the one possible problem. But your code completion suggests a rendition of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` with only one parameter, the completion block, but no progress block. `PFFile` takes two blocks, but other Parse objects don't. We'd have to see what data type `Restaurantes` is to diagnose this further. (`Restaurantes` is the name of the variable and we need to know what data type the object it is.)

Comment: Its type PFObject `var Restaurantes = PFObject(className:"Restaurantes")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet from the documentation is a `PFFile`, which has two renditions of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, one with just the completion block and another with both a completion block and a progress block.

Other Parse data types (e.g. `PFObject`) have `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` method only with the completion block, but no progress block. Your error message would suggest that `restaurantes` may not be a `PFFile`, but rather is one of these other data types. Without seeing how `restaurantes` was instantiated, it's hard to diagnose this further.

Comment: Its type PFObject... I cant do this with this kind of type? `var Restaurantes = PFObject(className:"Restaurantes")`

Comment: Yes, the progress block is not available for `PFObject`. That makes some sense, too, because a `PFObject` probably isn't large enough for a progress block to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to clarify:

1. you should save your file with:
   `file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` ...with progress block
2. Then, you must associate this file with your PFObject "Restaurantes":

   ```
   let newObject = PFObject(className: "Restaurantes")
       newObject["theFileFieldYouCreated"] = file
   newObject.saveInBackground()
   ```

In your case, you were trying to do the both at the same time.